# FFMPEG Overlay 1080X1920 video over 1280X720 video at a particular vertical position

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a 1080X1920 (vertical) video with alpha channel with a blank spot 500px north of the bottom.  This blank spot is 1080X607.

I have a 1280X720 sized video I want to position in that spot, so the 1280 video will have to be sized down to 1080 wide and then positioned 500px from the bottom and UNDER the video on top.

This is what I currently have, but it is failing beautifully.

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg  -i 1080x1920.mov -i 1280x720.MOV 
  -filter_complex "[1][0]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-0:main_h-overlay_h-500" 
  -c:v libx264 -profile:v high444 -pix_fmt yuv420p -level 3.1 -y  final.mp4
```

Comment: From the tag info: "Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on Super User or Video Production."

Comment: Ok, how can I move it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pad the rescaled 720p video with the correct margins and then carry out the overlay.

`ffmpeg  -i 1080x1920.mov -i 1280x720.MOV 
  -filter_complex "[1]scale=1080:-1,pad=1080:1920:0:1920-500-607[1v];[1v][0]overlay=0:0" 
  -c:v libx264 -profile:v high444 -pix_fmt yuv420p -level 3.1 -y final.mp4`

Note that high444 profile bitstream may not be compatible with many players.

Comment: Could you explain what each number in this pad command is doing? pad=1080:1920:0:1920-500-607?

Comment: pad=W:H:X:Y where W is the width of the new canvas, H its height. X and Y are co-ordinates where the input video is placed on the canvas, measured from top-left of canvas. See https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad-1

Comment: That makes sense, but your example has 3 numbers in each rather than 2? i.e. W:H:?:X-Y-?  What is the 0 and what is the 607?

Comment: Sorry, I find the ffmpeg docs to be less than helpful, as they don't break down each variable as I am asking here.  They seem to usually say, "W0-h3+Hr-A7" Will position your video at position 7.  Without explaining what each argument is actually doing. (Which is what has led me to ask this question in the first place.) . Thanks for your patience.

Comment: W = 1080, H = 1920, X = 0. Y = 1920-500-607 = 813.

Comment: Ah . Didn't realize that was a math equation.  Ok, this makes good sense now.  Thanks much for the extra info!